# Getting error while parsing timestamp string

Tags: go

I tried parsing

> Tue Apr 07 2020 11:17:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

But got the following error

> parsing time "Tue Apr 07 2020 11:17:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
>   as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "Tue Apr 07 2020 11:17:47
>   GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" as "2006" 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>   UTC

From the frontend i can get timestamp in any format depending on the location or zone.But, in go lang i'm trying to parse any timestamp and convert it to UTC to store in ledger.What is the correct way to handle this case?

```
t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, str)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```

Comment: You should use different layout instead of `time.RFC3339`. `time.RFC3339` is for dates like `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z`

Answer (score 2):

The reference time used in the `Go` time layouts is the specific time, `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`. To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look like formatted your way.

Since `MST` is `GMT-0700`, use your ref string that way in the first argument.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // Parsing your custom time format by using the reference time in your format.
    t1, err := time.Parse(
             "Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 GMT-0700",
             "Tue Apr 07 2020 11:17:47 GMT+0530")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(t1.UTC())
}
```

<sup>[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gGvWKnlDiot)</sup>

Comment: But my question is what to do when i don't know in which format i'm going to get the date and i also want to store all timestamp in UTC format

Comment: @alia: I'm afraid that's not possible, how would you expect the runtime to identify the type without providing it a reference string?

Comment: @alia: Updated to have the result in UTC

Comment: @alia, you have to call time.Parse multiple times, once for each supported format, and see which one doesn't return an error.